# querying data table selecting top n records giving error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I am implementing paging in my datalist.

For that i have to query on following datatable:

[image]

From this data table i want to select top n records(indexes) where index> n

I made following query:

```
DTResult.Select("top " & Integer.Parse(ddlPage.SelectedValue.ToString()), "Index > " & Integer.Parse(ddlPage.SelectedValue.ToString()))
```

note: ddlPage is my dropdown through which i am getting number 'n' i.e. selection of top 5/10/15... records.

Above query gives me error:

```
Cannot find column Index > 10.
```

As we can see records above index 10 are present.

Then also its giving me error.

What is wrong in my query?

Please help me.

(Syntax does not matters to me, answer in any of the language (c# or vb) can help me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want top ten where index > 10

```
DataRow[] results = DTResult.Select("Index > 10").AsEnumerable().Take(10);
```

This assumes that records are stored in order of index

Answer (score 2):

```
    DataRow[] drRow= datatTable.AsEnumerable().Take(10).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public DataRow[] Select(
    string filterExpression,
    string sort
)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/way3dy9w.aspx

try:

```
var n = ....;
var result = DTResult.AsEnumerable()
             .Where(row => row.Field<int>("Index") > n)
             .OrderBy(row => row.Field<int>("Index"))
             .Take(n);
```